# AWS Neptune Gremlin mergeE and mergeV don't use PartitionStrategy

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

It seems like mergeE and mergeV does not respect partition strategy, is this true?  I couldn't find any references in the docs

```
g.withStrategies(new PartitionStrategy(
partitionKey: "d", 
writePartition: "d", 
readPartitions: ["d"]))
.addV('dog').property(T.id, '1').property('name', 'dave')
.addV('dog').property(T.id, '2').property('name', 'jackie')
.mergeE([(T.label):'Sibling',created:'2022-02-07',(Direction.from):'1',(Direction.to):'2'])
```

In this case, when I use addV, V() returns the 2 vertexes, but E() returns nothing.

```
g.withStrategies(new PartitionStrategy(
partitionKey: "d", 
writePartition: "d", 
readPartitions: ["d"])).E()
```

However normal `g.E()` returns the edge.

If i just use merge to create a node, it also returns nothing

```
g.withStrategies(new PartitionStrategy(
partitionKey: "f", 
writePartition: "f", 
readPartitions: ["f"]))
.mergeV([(T.id):'1',(T.label):'Dog',name:'fakedog']).V()
```

but a normal `g.V()` returns my newly merged node (with no partition associated with it)

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you seem to have stumbled on to a bug. I've created [TINKERPOP-2994](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2994) for tracking.

The only workaround until that issues is resolved would be to manually write your `partitionKey` when using `mergeV()` and `mergeE()`:

```
mergeV([(T.id):'1',(T.label):'Dog',name:'fakedog', '_partition': 'd'])
```

and then you could use `PartitionStrategy` on the read easily enough when you do:

```
new PartitionStrategy(partitionKey: "_partition", 
                      writePartition: "d", 
                      readPartitions: ["d"]
```

Comment: Good to know; thanks for the workaround!  Let me play around with this.

Comment: How does `'_partition': 'd'` work exactly?  it seems to mean `<partkey>:<writepart>`, I tried `.mergeV([(T.id):'55',(T.label):'Dog',name:'fakedog', 'f': 'f', 'd': 'd']).V()` and I can see this in both d+f partitions.  Does this mean that partitionkey is just a property?

Comment: `partitionKey` in `PartitionStrategy` refers to the name of the property used to store the partiton value and yes, it's just a property. `PartitionStrategy` just automates the addition of the insertion of that key/value for writes and the use of it with filters for reads which can make your Gremlin otherwise extremely complicated to read.